# Can you run a command to re-size only certain image types in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, command-line, image-resize

The below command will re-size all images based on new specified dimensions:

*php bin/magento catalog:images:resize*

Is there a variable to add to run for a certain image type only? For example, swatch or thumb only?

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight forward answer to pass diff image types.

Because the way of doing resizing involves all the **Themes, Stores, and Image types** around 40-50 types (which are available in every theme file Namespace/Themename/etc/view.xml).

This runs for all the product images which will obviously consume more time.

One thing is to remove the unnecessary image tag from the etc/view.xml showing under `<images module="Magento_Catalog">` from your respective theme files.

comment out below or other tag which does not active:

```
<image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
            <width>140</width>
            <height>140</height>
        </image>
```

Another way, there is one private method [getViewImages](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Service/ImageResize.php#L250) is available in the file

Here, you can add a condition like in the **foreach** loop by overriding the [preference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html#override-a-method-using-preference-nodes) to this file. This will surely reduce a lot of time.

```
//Only type = image will be proceed
if ($imageData['type'] !== 'image') {
    continue;
}
```

You can create custom cli tool based on ImageResizeCommand the acting below:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Console/Command/ImagesResizeCommand.php#L81

1. Create a custom cli tool by using this - 
   https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html
2. In file `Console\WhateverNameCommand.php`, you can take the whole `ImagesResizeCommand.php` class from Magento.

   `$themeId = 1; //Get this from theme table
   $themeObject = $this->themeModelFactory->create()->load($themeId);
   $this->resize->resizeFromThemes($themeObject);`

Answer (score 1):

*This is related to v2.3.x*

I would assume not, looking at the code of [Magento 2 ImagesResizeCommand](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Console/Command/ImagesResizeCommand.php).

You might need to create a new custom module to override `function execute()` and possibly target information inside `$resizeInfo[] array`, for example **filename**.

(For example, you might create new custom *arguments* to the constructor in your module and target those conditions)

**NOTE: I see the upcoming v2.4x version will be vastly different - functions like `executeSync` and `executeASync` will handle the `execute()` independently.**

Comment: Thanks. Thought the answer would be no. Nothing online about at all at the moment. Issue occurs when you run the command on a huge catalogue, and it can take days to complete. Timing out in the middle regularly. Which then goes back to the start of the query on next run......

Comment: Yeah days for import/migration etc... and then when there are errors you need to start from the beginning can be extremely frustrating.  I guess you should try your custom module _(if you want to try and implement it)_ on a local installation with a few products / images only.  Please mark answer if it was helpful.